# Xdebug + VSCode on Ubuntu sees strange value for global supervariables

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am a PHP newbie and trying to install Xdebug for debugging. Following is my setup:

- PHP 8.1
- Ubuntu 22.04
- Visual Studio Code

This is the result of command `php -v`:

```
PHP 8.1.2 (cli) (built: Jul 21 2022 12:10:37) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.2, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

And the launch config for running debug in VSCode:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        

        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000,
            "runtimeExecutable": "/usr/bin/php",
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Xdebug seems to be working since I can run step in PHP code, however, super globals have strange value, different from accessing from web browsers, for example, `$_SERVER`:

**From Firefox localhost**:

```
[HTTP_HOST] => localhost[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0  
[HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8 
[HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.5 [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate, br 
[HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive 
[SERVER_SIGNATURE] =>Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) 
[SERVER_NAME] => localhost 
[SERVER_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1 
[SERVER_PORT] => 80 [REMOTE_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1 
[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/html
....
```

However, this if the `$_SERVER` from Xdebug:

```
[GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS] => JS ERROR;JS LOG
[LANGUAGE] => en_US:en
[USER] => viet
[LC_TIME] => en_CA.UTF-8
[XDG_SESSION_TYPE] => x11
[SHLVL] => 0
[HOME] => /home/viet
[DESKTOP_SESSION] => ubuntu
[GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE] => /usr/share/applications/code.desktop
[GTK_MODULES] => gail:atk-bridge
[GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE] => ubuntu
...
[VSCODE_AMD_ENTRYPOINT] => vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess
[VSCODE_HANDLES_UNCAUGHT_ERRORS] => true
[XDEBUG_MODE] => debug,develop
[XDEBUG_CONFIG] => client_port=40151
[PHP_SELF] => /var/www/html/pages/automation/index.php
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /var/www/html/pages/automation/index.php
[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/html/pages/automation/index.php
[PATH_TRANSLATED] => /var/www/html/pages/automation/index.php
[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => 
[REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1659989701.6132
[REQUEST_TIME] => 1659989701
```

Please notice that `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is empty here. It seems that it parse directly from my Linux global variable, not the localhost super variables?

May I know how can I fix this one so I have the correct super variables?

*[Update]*

As @LazyOne mentioned, I should use the "listen to Xdebug" config. However, when I run it, VS code keep listening without jump to breakpoint even after I browse the page by Chrome with Xdebug helper extension.
Following is some photos:
[image: VS code keep listening]

[image: Debug extension is running]

and the content of my */etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini*:

```
zend_extension="xdebug.so";
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/apache2/xdebug.log
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
```

Comment: How do you launch your debug session? What config do you use? It seems to me that you may be using "Launch currently open script" one, which is launching your current PHP script in CLI environment. In such a case it;s expected .. as CLI is not a web server and has no `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. You need to execute your scripts in a browser, so a web server is involved. for that you would need to use "Listen for XDebug"...

Comment: @LazyOne  Hi, indeed I used the wrong debug type, however, when I change to listen to xdebug, VS code keeps listening to port 9003 (I used lsof command to verify) but cannot see when I used Chrome to access to page, I turned on the xdebug helper extension as well, do I miss something here?

Comment: You have Xdebug v3.1.2 .. but your php.ini use Xdebug v2 params. They do almost nothing in v3. Go through https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN6ihpJSFDw

Comment: @LazyOne I found the reason: I should also add xdebug config in to apache2 php.init file. Such a newbie I am :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, as I have xdebug options in file /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini, only cli sessions will work correctly.
The resolution is to add same options to apache2 init file at */etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini*